# Excel: how to collapse several rows of sparse data into one using a grouping column

Tags: microsoft-excel

Ok so I want to turn the [current layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWV9X.png) into [this layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEtB7.png)

As you can see I want to get rid of the repeated titles and get rid of the empty cells. I'm thinking of creating a formula that for every seven rows after the first one gets rid of the titles and moves the other cells up, but I'm not sure how to write it or is it even possible to do something like that in Excel? There will be hundreds of rows, so I can't manually do this. I'm using Excel 2016 on a mac.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, thank you for checking it out! I'm using the 2016 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select any cell in your data Use Data>Get & Transform Data>From Table/Range to create a PowerQuery.

In the Power Query Editor, use Home>Transform>Group By and configure it like this:

[image]

When you click OK, you'll have the results you need.

[image]

Just click Home>Close&Load to put the data back into the workbook.

EDIT:

To do this with formulas, you can use something like this:

[image]

This is the formula in cell J2 in the image above.

```
=INDEX(B$2:B$15,SUMPRODUCT(N($A$2:$A$15=$I2),N(NOT(ISBLANK(B$2:B$15))),ROW(B$2:B$15))-1,1)
```

the `SUMPRODUCT` part will basically retrieve the row number of the non-empty cell in column B where column A matches the title in column I. `INDEX` will then retrieve the value from that row.

Please adjust the vertical size of your ranges to fit your data, but make sure that the $s are the same as above before you drag across and down to fill your consolidated table, as I have done in J2:O3 above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately I cannot use PowerQuery because I'm using a mac. Do you know a way to replicate that without using PowerQuery?

Comment: Had to remind myself how to do it... but anyway, please see the EDIT to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason i'm getting the #value! error, https://imgur.com/wZAqySH

Comment: Please put "Fake Title #1" in cell I2

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason that formula just copies "Fake Quote #1", https://imgur.com/a/46BC9lQ

Comment: You need to drag it across to the right to get the other columns.

Comment: Thanks, it works now, but i will have over 1000 data sets, so i would have to copy and paste the titles 1000 times, is it possible to edit the formula so that i could just drag down to get the titles?

Comment: You could copy column A to column I then use Data>Remove Duplicates

Comment: That worked. Thank you soo much!!!

Answer (score 0):

First, remove the blank cells in columns `B:G`:

1. Select columns `B:G`
2. From the `Home` tab choose `Find and Select` then `Go To Special`
3. Choose `Blanks` and hit `OK`. Note the blank cells selected.
4. From the `Home` tab choose `Delete`

Next, arrange the row headers in column `A`:

1. Select column `A`
2. Form the `Data` tab choose `Remove Duplicates`
3. Choose `Continue with current selection` and hit `Enter`

Your data should now be arranged as desired.

Should you ever upgrade to Excel 365, this can be done in a snap with Excel's new dynamic formulas:

1. In cell `I1` enter `=UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A,A:A<>""))`
2. In cell `J1` enter `=FILTER(B:B,B:B<>"")`
3. Copy cell `J1` to cells `K1:O1`